# Changing background color with document.querySelector() - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to change the body background color every 30 seconds but

```
document.querySelector('body').style.background = colors[active];​​
```

gives me

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Heres the context

```
// CYCLE BETWEEN BACKGROUND COLORS

var colors = ['#FAE03C', '#98DDDE', '#034F84'];
var active = 0;
setInterval(function() {

   // change background color of body
   document.querySelector('body').style.background = colors[active];​​

   //change button text hover color
   $("#myStyle").html('.button:hover {color: '+ colors[active] +'}')

   active++;
   if (active == colors.length) active = 0;
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine once you delete the invalid characters: https://jsfiddle.net/3pvxcfq5/

Comment: So delete that entire line and retype it to get rid of the bad characters. They're at the very end, so you can start on the next line, and backspace until you've eliminated that error.

Comment: Your code works fine, It seems you have some invalid characters following `;​​`

Comment: Ok thanks guy! Thought there was something wierd going on.